# Selecting count of distinct values that are not in another select

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I'd like to compare two tables as part of a data quality report. The result should be three columns summarizing the column column_x in the tables table_a and table_b:

1. Percent of column_x values in table_a that are not blank
2. Count of distinct values in table_a
3. Count of distinct values in table_a that are not in table_b

Columns 1 and 2 are easy to set up:

```
select
sum(CASE WHEN column_x = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) / count(*) AS percent_complete_in_a, -- column 1
count(DISTINCT column_x) AS distinct_values_A -- column 2
from table_A
```

But I can't figure out how to write my query so that column 3 can appear in the same results. I've tried a few variations on the following, but each one throws a syntax error in Postgres:

```
select
sum(CASE WHEN column_x = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) / count(column_x) AS percent_complete_in_a, -- column 1
count(DISTINCT column_x) AS distinct_values_A, -- column 2
count(DISTINCT column_x where column_x not in (select DISTINCT column_x FROM table_b)) as distinct_values_A_except_B -- column 3
from table_a
```

Is there a way to structure this query to make it show all three columns?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will help to use a left join for this. Note to avoid altering the count I have used a "select distinct" subquery which should not multiply any rows from table_a:

```
SELECT
      SUM(CASE WHEN a.column_x = '' OR a.column_x IS NULL 
                 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) / (COUNT(*) * 1.0)                 AS percent_complete_in_a
    , COUNT(DISTINCT a.column_x)                                       AS distinct_values_a
    , COUNT(DISTINCT case when b.column_x IS NULL then a.column_x end) AS distinct_values_A_except_B
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT column_x FROM table_b
      ) b ON a.column_x = b.column_x
;
```

Changes:

- added `IS NULL` in first case expression
- added `* 1.0` so you can get a decimal result for percent
- left join and count by case expression

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a subquery:

```
select avg( (column_x <> '')::float) as ratio_complete,
       count(distinct column_x) as distinct_values_A, -- column 2
       (count(distinct column_x) -
        (select count(distinct b.column_x)
         from table_b b
         where b.column_x = a.column_x
        )
       ) as distinct_a_not_in_b
from table_A a;
```